# How one defines a union type in Squeak FFI

Tags: smalltalk, ffi, squeak

I want to interface with a library that uses some union type for some structure fields, for example:

```
typedef struct {
    H5L_type_t          type;           /* Type of link                   */
    hbool_t             corder_valid;   /* Indicate if creation order is valid */
    int64_t             corder;         /* Creation order                 */
    H5T_cset_t          cset;           /* Character set of link name     */
    union {
        haddr_t         address;        /* Address hard link points to    */
        size_t          val_size;       /* Size of a soft link or UD link value */
    } u;
} H5L_info_t;
```

I didn't see any form of support in Squeak FFI for doing so.

Am I supposed to determine the longest member size by myself and stick to it?

Answer (score 1):

So after careful inspection of source code, I can tell that there was no support for union in Squeak FFI.

That does not have to stay like that, so I've published an update of Squeak FFI for supporting union.
See http://source.squeak.org/FFI/FFI-Kernel-nice.50.diff

`ExternalUnion` shares essentially the same code as `ExternalStructure` (as a subclass) except that it uses a constant `byteOffset` and a `max:` operator for accumulating the total byte size, rather than an incremented `byteOffset` with a `+` operator when iterating over the fields.

Comment: Fits perfectly into the hierarchy of `ExternalObject`. I agree that is useful to read `ExternalUnion` as a special case of `ExternalStructure`. How does the C standard talk about unions? Are those explained in relation to structs?

Comment: Subclassing ExternalStructure was a necessary hack for avoiding changes in the FFI plugin. But we can change that too if we want.